# Github Actions - Access a variable in a shell scrips

Tags: github, github-actions

I have this `bash` script where I am setting up some environment variables based on some conditions:

`script.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
...
test_result_emoji=":boom:"
critical_vulnerabilities_found="false"

if [ $critical2 -eq 0 ] && [ $high2  -eq 0 ]; then

test_result_emoji=":eight_spoked_asterisk:"

else

critical_vulnerabilities_found="true"
echo "CRITICAL_VULNERABILITIES_FOUND=${critical_vulnerabilities_found}" >> $GITHUB_ENV  
        
fi 
...
```

And I am calling above script from `github` actions as below:

```
      - name: Setting Up Pull-Request Body
        run: ./prerequisite.sh
```

My problem is, how can I access the variable `CRITICAL_VULNERABILITIES_FOUND` set in `prerequisite.sh` from another step?

```
      - name: Developers
        
        run: |
         echo <NEED-TO-GET-THE-VALUE-OF-CRITICAL_VULNERABILITIES_FOUND>
```

Comment: As you set the variable as a workflow env variable in the first step, to use it in the second step you should be able to use `echo ${{ env.CRITICAL_VULNERABILITIES_FOUND }}`. Did you try it?

Comment: There's no need for `env` context syntax, `$CRITICAL_VULNERABILITIES_FOUND` is enough.